# Use mono-font in Files manager?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, nautilus, fonts

Is it possible to enable a mono font in the files manager? (and only the files manager, not system wide)

Comment: Where is the Ubuntu version number? What have you already tried?

Comment: @David 20.04.3 LTS, So far, I checked files preferences, search here and in google. I also checked `/org/gnome/nautilus/preferences` in dconf editor, but didn't find anything

Comment: Please put that info in the question via edit not as a comment.